# Mysql compare and update table if there is a match

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables with the following structure:

*Product table:* "product_id", "name", "hashtags" (separated by |)

*Tags table:* "tag_id", "tag_name"

*Tag relations table:* "tag_id", "product_id"

**Here is my question:**
How can I compare "hashtags", separated by |, from the *product table* with "tag_name" in the *tags table* and if there is a match, add following "product_id" and "tag_id" to the *tag relations* table?

Answer (score 1):

you can use following query

```
insert into tag_relation_table(tag_id,product_id)
select tbl2.tag_id, tbl1.product_id 
from product_table tbl1
inner join tags_table tbl2 on locate(tbl2.tag_name,tbl1.hashtags)>0
```

Please let me know if it worked!

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Comment: @Gremlin, you are welcome. if it worked, then please accept the ans.